# Chrome returns undefined for cancelFullScreen AND webkitCancelFullScreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have written a simple function to toggle Fullscreen Mode on a web application. The application is only required to run in Chrome (eventually deployed under Kiosk mode), but there seems to be some strange behaviour with `cancelFullScreen` and `webkitCancelFullScreen`.

For example, here is the stripped down `toggleFullScreen` function:

```
var _isFullscreen = false;

function toggleFullScreen()
{
    var doc = document.documentElement,
        state = _inFullscreen,
        requestFunc = (doc.requestFullScreen || doc.webkitRequestFullScreen),
        cancelFunc = (doc.cancelFullScreen || doc.webkitCancelFullScreen);

    _inFullscreen = !(state);

    (!state) ? requestFunc.call(doc) : cancelFunc.call(doc);
}
```

For some strange reason, Chrome always reports that `cancelFunc` is `undefined`, even though `requestFunc` works fine.

Can anyone explain the reason for this, and a possible solution (without the need for jQuery or similar library plugins)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of @Tom Chung, and after playing around, it turns out that `cancelFullScreen` (and similarly `webkitCancelFullScreen` needs to be called on `document`, whereas `requestFullscreen` needs to be called on `document.documentElement`.

As such, the updated code as follows works fine:

```
function toggleFullScreen()
{
 var doc = document.documentElement,
 state = (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.isFullScreen),
 requestFunc = (doc.requestFullscreen || doc.webkitRequestFullScreen),
 cancelFunc = (document.cancelFullScreen || document.webkitCancelFullScreen);

 (!state) ? requestFunc.call(doc) : cancelFunc.call(document);
}
```

Comment: https://cdn.meme.am/instances/300x/72539910.jpg
lol so weird. would love to read this spec on this one XD

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggleFullScreen()
{
 //Post author DID NOT provide standards-compliant method at all.
 //Standards compliant approaches should detect first.
 //Prefixes are eventually removed / performance.

 if ()//standards here
 {
  //standards here
 }
 else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen)
 {
  document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();
 }
 else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen)
 {
  document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
 }
}
```

Not sure why document.documentElement.webkitCancelFullScreen is undefined.

Maybe (I guess) the reason is that full screen effect can only be start once at the same time.

However, document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen is required because document.documentElement give the element that is going to display in full screen.

Work perfectly in http://jsfiddle.net/8mVBK/16/show/

Update.

http://jsfiddle.net/8mVBK/17/

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this really isn't an ideal solution as it will require some maintenance if / when Chrome drop the `webkit` prefix from the Fullscreen API.

Comment: Amendments have been made. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I looked over your revised solution and actually found the answer. `cancelFullScreen` needs to be called on **`document`**, not `document.documentElement`!

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the developers working on [H5P](https://h5p.org), which supports fullscreen for all browsers supporting it. Below I have copied the parts of the code needed to exit fullscreen.

First we need to figure out the browser prefix

```
var fullScreenBrowserPrefix;

// Detect if we support fullscreen, and what prefix to use.
if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
  /**
   * Browser prefix to use when entering fullscreen mode.
   * undefined means no fullscreen support.
   * @member {string}
   */
  fullScreenBrowserPrefix = '';
}
else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
  var safariBrowser = navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/(\d)/);
  safariBrowser = (safariBrowser === null ? 0 : parseInt(safariBrowser[1]));

  // Do not allow fullscreen for safari < 7.
  if (safariBrowser === 0 || safariBrowser > 6) {
    fullScreenBrowserPrefix = 'webkit';
  }
}
else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  fullScreenBrowserPrefix = 'moz';
}
else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
  fullScreenBrowserPrefix = 'ms';
}
```

Here's the code that invokes the correct exit-fullscreen-function:

```
if (fullScreenBrowserPrefix === '') {
  document.exitFullscreen();
}
else if (fullScreenBrowserPrefix === 'moz') {
  document.mozCancelFullScreen();
}
else {
  document[fullScreenBrowserPrefix + 'ExitFullscreen']();
}
```

The code is copied from https://github.com/h5p/h5p-php-library/blob/master/js/h5p.js